# Python - Webscraping POST login expired

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to download a file from an network device. Therefore i need to be logged in to get to the download endpoint.

I copied the `POST` curl of the login request to the website and converted it to a python request that looks like so.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': 'http://192.168.18.96',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'http://192.168.18.96/v1/base/cheetah_login.html',
    'Cookie': 'testcookie; SID=a243eb355e16a079226a443d4a0c5f0ff453f032a99e8752084796c681aff36a66de4e88bb0aad7f272b3be8fe011c9364f4659efcc0d08f2ee98f7180944760; testcookie; Language_In_Use=',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

data = {
    'CSRFToken': '1679065361ce165a07724a0553789eee63938e08ab7be0148728a5f79878469cefbb3bfb6938ed526996fd9cee8e8c307ad4177e4abb257f4ae8be878e88a8f40a2ad97e92',
    'uname': 'admin',
    'pwd': 'password',
    'err_flag': '',
    'err_msg': '',
    'submt': '',
}

response = requests.post('http://192.168.18.96/v1/base/cheetah_login.html', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

If i run that `POST` i get an expired response back that looks like so.

```
<!--
/*********************************************************************
* Copyright 2016-2021 Broadcom.
**********************************************************************
*
* @filename 
*
* @purpose Login page
*
* @comments 
*
* @create 
*
* @author 
* @end
*
**********************************************************************/
-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<LINK REL=stylesheet HREF="/v1/base/style.css" TYPE="text/css">
<link rel=stylesheet href="/v1/base/nanoscroller.css" TYPE="text/css">
<META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">   
  <TITLE>NETGEAR M4300-52G</TITLE>       <!-- Cheetah Page Title  -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/v1/base/favicon.ico">             <!-- fav icon -->

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/v1/base/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/v1/base/js/jquery.cookie.js?v="12.0.17.7"'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/v1/base/js/ng_help.js?v="12.0.17.7"'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/v1/base/js/nav_nls.js?v="12.0.17.7"'></script>


  <style>

  .loginPage_inlineEr_padding
  {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  h1 
  {
    font: 14pt Arial;
    color: #672E8F;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  </style>
</head>

<script>
var timeOut = 0;
var timerNum = 0;
var presentHost;
function  expiredLoad()
{
  timerNum = setInterval(reloginTimeout, 1000);
  var head = document.getElementById("expiredmessage");
  var timeRemaining = 10-timeOut;
  presentHost = top.location.protocol+ "//" +top.location.host;
  var tag = "<a href=\""+presentHost+"\">"+js_NLS_here+"</a>";
  var msg = js_NLS_valMapSessionExpiredMsg1 + tag + js_NLS_valMapSessionExpiredMsg2 + String(timeRemaining) + js_NLS_seconds;
  head.innerHTML = msg; 
}

function  reloginTimeout()
{
  timeOut = timeOut + 1;
  if(timeOut == 10)
  {
    clearInterval(timerNum);
    var presentHost;
    presentHost = top.location.protocol+ "//" + top.location.host;
    top.location.replace(presentHost);
  }  
  var head = document.getElementById("expiredmessage");
  var timeRemaining = 10-timeOut;
  presentHost = top.location.protocol+ "//" +top.location.host;
  var tag = "<a href=\""+presentHost+"\">"+js_NLS_here+"</a>";
  var msg = js_NLS_valMapSessionExpiredMsg1 + tag + js_NLS_valMapSessionExpiredMsg2 + String(timeRemaining) + js_NLS_seconds;
  head.innerHTML = msg; 
}

</script>
<body onLoad="expiredLoad()">

  <div class="spacer100Percent">
      <div class="loginPage_mainPadding top">
        <div class="netgearLogoPadding">
          <a href="http://www.netgear.com/">
            <img width="138" alt="Netgear" src="/v1/base/images/Netgear-logo.png"/>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="separator13"></div>
          <div>
            <label class="productName">
              M4300-52G ProSAFE 48-port 1G and 2-port 10GBASE-T and 2-port 10G SFP+
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1 id = "expiredmessage"> The login page has expired. Will be redirected to login page Automatically </h1>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer_image" class="bottom_image" style="height: 408px; padding-top: 40px;"></div>
  <div id="branding_text" class="footer paddingLeft25 separator25" style="position: absolute; top: 745px; line-height: 25px; vertical-align: middle;">
        &copy; 2022 NETGEAR, Inc. All rights reserved.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already tried to work within a `requests.session` and `webscrape` the CSRF token, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, where the problem was sitting. I played again with sessions and i finally got it to work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


username = 'admin'
password = 'password'

url = 'http://192.168.18.96/v1/base/cheetah_login.html'
download_url = 'http://192.168.18.96/upload_download/startup-config'



with requests.session() as s:

    page = s.get(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    csrf_token = html.find('input', {'name': 'CSRFToken'})['value']

    data = {
        'CSRFToken': csrf_token,
        'uname': username,
        'pwd': password
    }


    response = s.post(url, data=data)

    with open('index.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.text)

    config = s.get(download_url)
    print(config.text)
```